# Acrobat pdf importAnXFDF from external sources

Tags: php, acrobat, xfdf

I have created a pdf form using acrobat with below script.

Below the script:

```
function importXFDF() {
    var url = "https://<Server>/first-form_data.xfdf";
    this.importAnXFDF(url);
}
importXFDF();
```

If any users download and open the form i am trying to Prefill the form values from XFDF file  using importAnXFDF() function. XFDF file is dynamically created by php script.

The issue is: if i pass any local xfdf file then the values are populated. But it fails if it is server file. Is it possible to import data to pdf form from server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't import an XFDF from a URL, only from a local file path. Instead, create an FDF file on your server then in your form, use submitForm where the URL is the URL to your server plus "#FDF". Thi will tell Acrobat to expect an FDF to be returned. Return the FDF using application/vnd.fdf as the mime type. Acrobat should populate the values.

Comment: It works! thanks! Also it is showing popup to choose file. Is there any option to skip?

Comment: Is the "#FDF" at the end of the URL? That should tell Acrobat to just import the response rather than prompt for a file.